# What should we use with Hibernate and Springboot. SesssionFactory or EntityManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to Hibernate and springboot. I would like someone to tell me when and why should we use EntityManager or SessionFactory? Also please brief upon whether we should use Java based Configuration or XML based configuration for dB and other configs.

The above query is regarding the project that I am working on:

**PROJECT:**

I have a simple REST based API project using Springboot and hibernate where I need to build a registration and login mechanism using GET and POST requests. 
Whenever I am trying to make a POST request to create a resource(create a new user in this case) I get the following error on POSTMAN and also Eclipse IDE:

**POST REQUEST I made using POSTMAN**

```
{
    "userId": "12345",
    "pin": "1234"
}
```

**ERROR ON POSTMAN While Making a POST REQUEST**

```
    {
    "timestamp": 1551809931747,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
    "message": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder",
    "path": "/employee/register"
}
```

**FULL STACK TRACE OF THE ERROR**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(HibernateTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:341) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at com.cerner.project.dao.EmployeeDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b4cb760.registerUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cerner.project.controller.EmployeeController.registerUser(EmployeeController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

What might be the issue causing this error? All I am trying to do is a simple POST.

Below are my files:
**User.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="pin")
    //@ColumnTransformer(read = "sha1(pin)",write = "sha1(?)")
    private String pin;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private List<UserLog> userLog=new ArrayList<UserLog>();

    public List<UserLog> getUserLog() {
        return userLog;
    }

    public void setUserLog(List<UserLog> userLog) {
        this.userLog = userLog;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public User() {

    }
    public User(int userId, String pin) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.pin= pin;
    }
    //CLOVER:OFF
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userId=" + userId + ", pin=" + pin + "]";
    }
    //CLOVER:ON
}
```

**EmployeeDao.Java**

```
        package com.cerner.project.dao;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.cerner.project.model.Team;
    import com.cerner.project.model.User;
    import com.cerner.project.model.UserLog;

    //@Service
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class EmployeeDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        private Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        public User registerUser(User user) {
            int userId=user.getUserId();
            user.setUserId(userId);
            String userPin=user.getPin();
            user.setPin(userPin);
            return user;
        }

        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();
              User user1=new User(11111,"1234");
            User user2=new User(22222,"4321");
            users.add(user1);
            users.add(user2);
            getSession().beginTransaction();
            getSession().save(user1);
            getSession().save(user1);
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
            return users;
        }
    }
```

**EmployeeController.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cerner.project.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.cerner.project.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        employeeDao.registerUser(user);
        return("SUCCESS");
    }


    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return employeeDao.getAllUsers();

    }

}
```

**DBConfiguration.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@Configuration
//@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClass;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.cerner.project" });
        return factory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory factory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(factory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`EntityManager` is part of JPA (Java Persistence API), which is the standard Java EE API for object-relational mapping. Hibernate is one of the available implementations of JPA, and `SessionFactory` is part of Hibernate.

This means that if you use `SessionFactory` directly, you're using Hibernate-specific functionality, whereas when you use `EntityManager`, you're using JPA and you're not tying your code to one specific JPA implementation such as Hibernate.

Therefore, it would be better to use `EntityManager`, which makes it possible (in principle) to later swap out Hibernate for a different JPA implementation. So, unless you have a good reason, for example, you need to use Hibernate-specific features which are not available through JPA, use `EntityManager` instead of `SessionFactory`.

If you're using `EntityManager` and you still need the Hibernate-specific `Session` because you need to do something Hibernate-specific, you can get it by using `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`:

```
Session session = EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

However, an even better option is to use [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa), which makes working with the database even easier - you won't have to implement DAOs, just declare repository interfaces. You won't have to use either `EntityManger` or `SessionFactory` directly when you use Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Even when using plain JPA it is pretty easy to obtain a `Session` using `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`. You might want to add that to the answer for completeness.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please help me solve the error I posted above?

Comment: @KshitizBathwal Try this: in `EmployeeDAO`, autowire `private EntityManager entityManager;` instead of `private SessionFactory sessionFactory;` and then change the line in the method `getSession()` from: `return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` to: `return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`

Comment: @Jesper I tried what you mentioned above. Now getting this error
Description:
Field entityManager in com.cerner.project.dao.EmployeeDAO required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found.


Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' in your configuration. In my previous error, atleast the application was starting but now its not even starting.

Comment: @KshitizBathwal Sounds like you might be missing some dependencies in your project, but it's hard to help you with your complete project setup through a website like StackOverflow, because I can't see your whole project... You can find good tutorials here: [Spring Guides](https://spring.io/guides), for example this one: [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) shows you how to make a simple Spring Boot REST ws. Or [this one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) if you want to include a DB.